# sprintf keeps returning the same string

Tags: c, char, printf

I'm writing a program that uses sprintf to convert integers to strings. To give you more context,my program has a parent process that spawns as many children as needed to compute the sums of the command line arguments given. Each child process receives 2 arguments to compute. That whole part was easy, it's just the return process that is confusing me. I'm getting the sums back and now I need to turn them into strings. So I thought something like this would work,

```
 for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
      if (array[i] == 0) {
           break;
      }
      temp = array[i];
      sprintf(sums, "%d", temp);
      argv[i]=*sums;
 }

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
 }
```

However, instead of getting output that looks like this:

```
argv[0] = ./master
argv[1] = 3
argv[2] = 7
argv[3] = 11
argv[4] = 15
etc...
```

I get this:

```
argv[0] = ./master
argv[1] = 15
argv[2] = 15
argv[3] = 15
argv[4] = 15
etc...
```

I can't figure out why the last sum is repeating itself. I have a feeling that it has to do with the way I'm using sprintf, but I've spent almost a whole day trying to figure this out and I'm legitametly stuck. By the way, I've declared array at the top of my program as

> `int array[10]={0};`

Comment: `argv[i]=*sums;` is not how you copy strings. It's also a very poor idea to overwrite `argv`.

Comment: To allocate memory and copy a string: [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to c programming. Would I have to allocate memory outside of the for-loop?

Comment: @kaylum for some unknown reasons `strdup` did not make it into the official C-standard (current: 9899:2011). BTW: nobody took the time yet to do an entry in the documentation here or am I just too stupid to find it?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Thanks, I never quite realised that.

Comment: @DaveL. As your code stands it would make more sense to allocate memory inside the loop. Because you need a new string buffer for each iteration of the loop. Also note that array indices in C start from 0 not 1.

Comment: @kaylum, thanks, I know they don't. I just didn't want to overwrite ./master which is stored at position 0. My hopes was to pass argv again to the same function I've already implemented which uses a hash to get the correct arguments from argv, and if I started at 0, my hash wouldn't work or I'd have to make a special case.

Comment: As mentioned, it is a bad idea to use `argv` as that has a very specific purpose in C programs. Just create a seperate array for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Combining your code, and folks' comments, I believe this is what is being suggested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char number_string[128];
    char *my_argv[100];
    int my_argc = 0;
    int array[] = { 3, 7, 11, 15, 0 };

    my_argv[my_argc++] = strdup(argv[0]);

    for (int i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++) {
        sprintf(number_string, "%d", array[i]);
        my_argv[my_argc++] = strdup(number_string);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < my_argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, my_argv[i]);
        free(my_argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't have `strdup()` for some reason, you can do the equivalent using `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.  Reusing `argv[]` doesn't make sense as it's size is limited to `argc` which you're not even considering.

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./master
argv[0]: ./master
argv[1]: 3
argv[2]: 7
argv[3]: 11
argv[4]: 15
>
```

Comment: You can use `argv` as a variable name, but you have to change the `argv` in `main` to something differrent, e.g.: `int main(int ac, char **av)` if you want to use that name in `main`.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi, I wasn't concerned he was reusing the `argv` name, I was concerned that he was reusing the `argv[]` array, regardless of its name.  Though I don't see a reason to reuse the name as what is he going to do with the array that expects it to be named something specific?